# Subprocess.Popen route child process stdout,stderr to parent process

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen

I'd like to call a background task using `subprocess.Popen` that will run a server on the background, that suppose to print some meaningful messages upon some events like incoming http message.

I want to get those logs and merge them with the parent process so I could observe the whole flow, which include other components besides this server.

According to documentation

> PIPE indicates that a new pipe to the child should be created.

So I've tried the follow call, but failed to trace the child process logs.

```
res = subprocess.Popen("python3 http_server.py", 
                       shell=True,
                       stdin=PIPE, 
                       stdout=PIPE, 
                       stderr=STDOUT, 
                       close_fds=True)
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: What issue do you have with this? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'd like to the printouts from the background child process being constantly appear on the parent process stdout.

Comment: Won't that happen "automatically" if you do not not pipe the stdout/stdin? The text will go to the same terminal - however not nicely ordered.

Comment: Yes ,you're right. So this leads me to the question of what benefit does the `subprocess.PIPE` gives you anyway ?

Comment: It allows your calling program to process the output of the subprocess. Perhaps you want to do something else with it, rather than just print it for the user?

Comment: ok, that's some capability i'd rather have. So I've tried storing them in the memory of the parent process using `iter` command but it didn't work. Perhaps you can share a minimal example here ?

Comment: If you use `PIPE` the output is stored in `res.stdout` which ought to be usable as an iterator (e.g. in a `for` loop). Look into that and then ask a new question if you cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing all the options and only provide the script to the subprocess. It should display all logs for the child process in the same terminal.

```py
res = subprocess.Popen("python3 http_server.py")
```

Comment: Or set it to `None` to make it more explicit (it is the default value:
https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

`res = subprocess.Popen("python3 http_server.py", stderr=None)`